# Replace _.forEach with something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, lodash

I have  a problem. I've made a long function which has 4 _.forEach in it. I want to replace some of this _.forEach with something else from lodash or something else.

So, I have many arrays of object and I want to iterate over both of them and compare the values from both of them. I've made it, but I want a better solution to have a cleaner code.

Here is my function:

```
function refreshFruits() {
     _.forEach($scope.fruits, function(fruit, index){
        _.forEach(vm.toUpdate.somethingLikeFruits, function(somethingLikeAFruit, dIndex) {
             .forEach(somethingLikeAFruit.P, function(dep, nIndex) {
                     _.forEach(fruit.l, function(leg, legindex) {
                                if(leg.Name === dep.LegName) {
                                    leg.Disc = dep.Discl;
                                    leg.Fore = dep.Projection;
                                }
                 });

          });

      });
  }); 

}
```

where fruits is an array of objects, vm.toUpdate.somethingLikeFruits is also an array of objects and P and l are arrays.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like a homework from school.

Comment: Please post a sample of your `Array` of `Objects` as well as an expected result. You may take a look at lodash `find` method.

Comment: If this is homework then mark it like so. Then you can be guided to think for yourself instead of 'receiving' the end solution with no work on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Split the refreshFruits() function up into more functions.

Like:

```
function refreshFruite(){
}

function updateFruit(fruit){
}

function updateFruitValue(fruit, index){
}
```